# Start laravel project issue

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I'm in trouble with starting a laravel project.
I'm new with laravel and php framework but I'm trying to learn them.
I copied one project from web, I called the project 'blog' but i don't know how to start it,I made all the migration and the database is correct but I don't know what to write on the google bar.
i tried 'localhost/blog' and other solutions but they don't work.
I'm using windows 10 and XAMPP.

Comment: try this `Localhost/blog/public/`
and if you have route name then use the route name after public

Answer (score 1):

Normally, every laravel project needs to be installed & initialized.

Therefore, you should do the following steps:

- run `composer install` in the project directory
- generate a project key via `php artisan key:generate`
- link your web server's document / root to the `public` directory

A good starting point is the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation#installing-laravel) and the [Quickstart](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart). If you plan to build your first application, [here](https://laravel-news.com/your-first-laravel-application) is another great tutorial by Laravel-News.com

Comment: thank you for the answer. but when i run composer install, it's already installed. and about the 3rd point, when i navigate to localhost/blog/public  , it says  'Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found'.thank you for your time.

Comment: it is not,sorry.

Comment: Have you configured a v-host and added a test domain (f.e. blog.test) to your hosts file? More details about using laravel with XAMPP can be found [here](https://www.codementor.io/magarrent/how-to-install-laravel-5-xampp-windows-du107u9ji)

Answer (score 1):

-step 1: you open xampp and start apache and mysql.

-step 2: run command: "php artisan key:generate".

-step 3: write url: "localhost/blog/public" to run your project. If browser display text "Laravel", that mean you run your project correctly;

Answer (score 0):

If you copied the project then you have to run

**1st Composer Install or Composer Update**

Make Sure composer is installed in your machine with global path variable

**2nd thing update the .env file**

Comment: global path variable?.sorry, i'm new to these thing.

Comment: yes open cmd and run composer if its not working like command not found its not defined globally. else its already added to your global variable path.

Comment: and run php artisan:serve (from your project directory only)  you will get your project URL copy that in browser you will see your project.

Answer (score 0):

Watch a few videos before you dive into it, get familiar with Composer and NPM.
Know what role they play in Laravel.

I suggest Laracasts, It's like netflix for your career/hobby ;)
Else try to find some Laravel 5.4+ tutorials.